# Integrating MS Word in a MEAN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ms-word, mean-stack

I have built a web application using MEAN stack. I would like to add the following feature.

There are two types of users; admin and regular user. The admin should be able to create Word Document Templates on the application.  Then the regular user should be able to pick one of the templates and start working on it. When picking a template, the system should actually make a copy of that template and allow the user edit the copy, not the actualy template. The document should be opened in local Microsoft Word. It should sync with the template when making changes.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I have been searching for the last couple of days and I couldn't find any leads. Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, what i would suggest is

Admin will create  templates using admin panel, User will select already created templates from the list and start editing.

In this case, you don't need to integrate ms-word in your application. What you need is a HTML editor. Admin will create templates using an HTML editor and will save it to the Database as html itself.

When a user logged in, we will show all the templates from the database using the same html editor. When user select a template, the can start editing on it and save it to the database with a different ID and added_by attribute. so this will save as a different document in the database

[quill editor](https://quilljs.com/) is a perfect solution in this case.

Comment: I have tried all wysiwyg editors. The problem is, none of them provides all the features that MS Word provides. Also, there are already a set of users for this system and it would be a major change that they need to adapt to.

Comment: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/overview/ what about this?

Comment: Sorry, this would not work. All my users want MS Word to be implemented.